# How to clear cache memory on linux machine for a user?

Tags: linux, caching, memory

I am running a c++ tool on Linux machine. The tool crashes because of memory issues. I have checked the RAM details of my machine.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15798      15747         50          0         15      12758
-/+ buffers/cache:       2972      12825
Swap:         8001        345       7655
```

There is hardly no space to run my application.
How can I safely clear the selected cache memory so that the tool executes.(To do that how can I list the cache memory details)
I need at least 3GB of memory to run my application.

I did not try to erase cache as it may kill the current application.

Note: The tool takes at least 40 hours to reach memory threshold limit.
RedHat Linux

Please help.

Comment: Your problem is not the cache, and clearing the cache memory is not the solution to your problem.  See https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1):

I am try this on my linux **ubuntu 19.04** and it successfully cleared the cache

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

OR

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

> `# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
>
> ---
>
> **Note**: The `# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` command is used to clean up your memory from pagecache, dentries and inodes.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create a file and copy below content in /bin/mfree file. give it to execution permission by running `chmod +x /bin/mfree`. Now you can run mfree command to clear cache memory along with after/before report.

Note: You can choose file name anything.

```
#!/bin/bash
#purpose: purging cache memory
#author: bablish jaiswal
free -wh > ~/old #moving file to store last memory report before purging
purging () {
sudo sync; sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
sudo sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches #droping chache meory
}
report(){
echo -e "\n\n\n\nServer $(curl -s -4 ident.me;echo)'s cache Purging report:-\n-----Before Purging----\n$(cat ~/old)\n\n-----After Purging-----\n$(free -wh)\nTimeStamp:- $(TZ='Asia/Kolkata' date)\n\n"  
}
purging > /dev/null 2>&1 && report ||  echo -e "Kindly run with sudo rights\nExample:- sudo mfree" #guide to run
```

mfree command's sample output is shown below.

[image]